# How to create pop up when focusing input on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

In my mobile site menu, i have an input field, and I need to have a new window poping up when i click(focus) on that input field, and that new window should cover entire screen and contain bigger input field, button and X for closing.

I tried everything but just cant make it happen right on both, android and iphones.

This is my mobile menu :

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Gallery</li>
    <li><input type="text" class="field" name="s" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Suche', 'osk' ); ?>" />
    <button type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Suche', 'osk' ); ?>"><span class="icon-search"></span></button></li>
</ul>
```

And this is js I've tried but doesnt do the job

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $( '.menu_mobile #s' ).focus(function() {
        $('.search').wrap('<div class="input_focus" style="position: fixed; background: white; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 20% 0;"></div>'); 
$(this).focus();    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: kindly post the code you tried and what behaviour you got. People can try to fix that instead of writing from scratch

Comment: @MilanMilosevic ... please post the code in your post, not in the comments.

Comment: Posted the js I've tried, a friend tried to help me with that idea, but we couldnt make it work right.